# How do I set an image for ERC20 tokens on Etherscan?

Tags: erc-20, explorers

[image]

The picture above is an example.

I want to set an image on the ERC20 token I created and display it on the Explorer page.

Can anyone tell me how to set it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to click here and register as the owner.

You will need to connect with the wallet that deployed the smart contract to verify ownership.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the instructions below to add a logo/image to your crypto token on Etherscan. You will need to:

1. Log into Ether Scan Input your token address into Ether Scan and
   navigate to your tokens page
2. On your tokens page click on “Edit” in
   the profile summary section
3. You will receive the Update Token
   Information Page popup
4. You will then be prompted to confirm your
   address with your private key
5. Then you can complete the required
   information to add your token image / logo to Ether Scan

https://cryptomarketpool.com/how-to-add-an-image-logo-to-your-crypto-token/